# Hibernate pessimistic lock between two web apps

Tags: hibernate

I have two different web applications that update a database table entity. The two different application use same structure of entity (but the apps have their own separate code for these entities)

```
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {
    // Fields
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Double credit;

    //..setters getters

}
```

These two apps have their own service that updates the credit of the user.

App1 locks the user entity with the ff:

```
User user = (User) userDao.get(User.class, userName,LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

//update here
```

App2 locks the entity  with the ff:

```
User user = (User) userDao.get(User.class, userName,LockMode.UPGRADE);

//update here
```

Now, there was a case of race condition where both app update the user credit at same time.Both app retrieved a credit of 1.0 during invocation of `userDao.get(...)`. App1 would add 10 while App2 would add 20. After both transactions were commited, the user credit is 21. But the expected user credit after these updates should be 31. Is it due to the LockMode being different between these two apps (ie, LockMode.UPGRADE && LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)?. Or is it because they run on different web servers (Note: they use same database). Based on my understanding of lockmode pessimistic it should be 31 because the other transaction will wait for the transaction that 1st acquired the lock. Can someone explain a possible reason for this update anomally?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_READ` instead of  `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`. Accordingly to the docs:

> PESSIMISTIC_READ. The entity manager locks the entity as soon as a
>   transaction reads it. The lock is held until the transaction
>   completes. This lock mode is used when you want to query data using
>   repeatable-read semantics. In other words, you want to ensure that the
>   data is not updated between successive reads. This lock mode does not
>   block other transactions from reading the data.
>
> PESSIMISTIC_WRITE. The entity manager locks the entity as soon as a
>   transaction updates it. This lock mode forces serialization among
>   transactions attempting to update the entity data. This lock mode is
>   often used when there is a high likelihood of update failure among
>   concurrent updating transactions.

With `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` you can have dirty reads.